# how to hide url or src video in jwplayer 7 or flowplayer v_6.0.5?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, flowplayer

I want to hide URL video from inspect element in browser.
I want to encrypt it and need to stop IDM about download video.

```js
flowplayer("#fp-hlsjs", {
  key: "$**********",
  logo: "<?= Yii::$app->request->getBaseUrl()?>/icons/coolzone2.png",
  clip: {
    title: '<?= $model->post_title; ?>',
    sources: [{
      type: "video/mp4",
      src: "<?= $model->movie_link;?>"
    }]
  },
  rtl: false,
  splash: true,
  ratio: 5 / 11.4,
  embed: false,
  brand: {
    text: "Cool",
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do ajax request to get the video location,

```
var video_source;
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: your url,
     success: function (data) {
        video_source = data.d;
     }
   });
```

Then, in your flowplayer function you can do

```
 sources: [{
      type: "video/mp4",
      src: video_source
    }]
```